# When will the first Falcon-9 send something to the Moon? Will it be iSpace's HAKUTO-R?

Tags: spacex, the-moon, falcon-9, lander, spaceflight-firsts

The Teslarati article [SpaceX customer iSpace updates Falcon 9-launched Moon lander, rover plans](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-customer-ispace-falcon-9-moon-lander-rover/) says

> Japanese commercial space company iSpace has provided an updated schedule for its first private missions to the Moon, both set to launch on Falcon 9 rockets and land on the Moon as early as 2021 and 2023.

The article also links to iSpace's 22 Aug, 2019 news item [Mission Timeline Adjustment for the HAKUTO-R Program](https://ispace-inc.com/news/?p=1376)

**Question:** When will the first Falcon-9 send something to the Moon? Will it be [iSpace's HAKUTO-R](https://ispace-inc.com/hakuto-r/)? Is this the first and/or only serious plan to hire a Falcon-9 to get to the Moon?

**note:** For the purposes of this question, the F-9 does not necessarily need go all the way to the Moon itself.

Comment: I think that was already claimed by Beresheet, no?

Comment: @jkavalik if that's the answer, then *that's the answer!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imho the Israeli SpaceIL [Beresheet Moon lander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beresheet) already satisfies your question.

It was developed to compete in the Google Lunar X-Prize
It was launched by F9 on February 22, 2019 as a secondary payload with *Nusantara Satu (PSN-6)* and it separated into supersynchronous GTO. It then moved to the Moon under its own power and crashlanded there on 11 April 2019.

Comment: Yes it does indeed. I totally forgot that SpaceX was the launch provider, thanks!